# Umbraco Event handler - Raise Custom UI Error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, event-handling, umbraco7

I am using **`Umbraco 7.2.4.`**

I have added a functionality to publish an event.

How can I raise custom Error message while there is Exception in my code, and display it to the user?

I have tried the following code :

```
var clientTool = new Umbraco.Web.UI.Pages.ClientTools((System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler);
clientTool.ShowSpeechBubble(SpeechBubbleIcon.Error, "Choose first a content page", "Page has not been added.");
```

But it's throws the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler' to type 'System.Web.UI.Page'

What am I doing wrong here ?
Or, Is there another way to raise custom error?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a simple way to add custom error messages in Umbraco 7.  However, there is a workaround that involves intercepting the request to the API and modifying the default error message.  See the WebApiHandler described in [this thread](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/developing-umbraco-7-packages/53699-User-Message-%28former-Speech-bubble%29-in-custom-event) and the technique of using the AdditionalData property a bit further down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the error in your controller or null check(if a == null), if it does occur then return a view showing the error.Like:

```
if(myValue == null)
{
    return View("~/Views/ErrorView.cshtml", model);
}
```

or

```
try{
    //try do something
}
catch(Exception e){
    //log your exception
    return View("~/Views/ErrorView.cshtml", model); // Model is Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel

}
```

Also check TempData in MVC.

Comment: I don't want error page. I want error notification on the page  like when there is umbraco error or saving event.

Comment: yes that is why I said to look to TempData. you could do in your controller TempData["errorMessage"] = "my message", and then return back to currentPage and display whatever value in TempData["errorMessage"] - I will try to provide a good example

Comment: Look at http://pastie.org/10696209#1  - this is an example from a project I am currently working on.
And on your View/Page you just display the value in TempData. I hope this is what you are looking for.